# Unit Test failing promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise, chai

I am new to asynchronous programming. I am writing a test case for the following example code.

```
someAsync(text) {
  try {
    //do something and resolve result
    return Promise.resolve(result);
  } catch (err) {
    return Promise.reject(new Error(`Failure ${err}`));
  }
}
```

I am testing it with the following code:

```
it('should throw error when called', (done) => {
  const mymodule = new MyModule(args);
  mymodule.someAsync('something that causes failure').catch((err) => {
    expect(err).to.exist;
    expect(err.message).to.contains('This should pass');
    done(err);
  });
});
```

This test case fails, assertions pass and then after done again it throws error. 
Please tell me where am I going wrong?

Comment: *This test case fails, assertions pass and then after done again it throws error* - it's unclear what you mean. If there are errors, please, list them all. Testing framework is not listed. Is it Mocha?

Comment: Yes its mocha. 
Please pardon my punctuations :)
The test case fails after reaching done(err). Test case fails with the same error message that passes in the assertion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`done(err)` makes a spec to fail. Since it's expected error, it shouldn't fail a spec, it should be `done()` instead.

Mocha doesn't need `done` to handle promises, a promise can be returned from a spec.

It likely should be:

```
it('should throw error when called', () => {
  const mymodule = new MyModule(args);
  return mymodule.someAsync('something that causes failure').catch((err) => {
    expect(err).to.exist;
    expect(err.message).to.contain('This should pass');
  });
});
```

Also, it's not evident from the listed code that `expect(err.message).to.contain('This should pass')` assertion is true.

Comment: Thanks it worked. 'This should pass' was misleading, I wanted to convey that this test case should pass. anyways, done() was not required. I removed and it worked.

Comment: You're welcome. It's *either* `return mymodule.someAsync...` or `done()`, the former is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

This might or might not have anything to do with your error, but that does not really look like asynchronous code.  Something like this might make more sense:

```
const someAsync = (text) => new Promise((resolve, reject)) => {
  try {
    // do something and capture result
    resolve(result);
  } catch (err) {
    reject(new Error(`Failure ${err}`));
  }
})
```

As estus' comment said, we probably need the actual error and the test framework to diagnose further.